# Create single array from MySQL with PHP/PDO

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I am trying to create a single array from a db table that has few rows like:

```
--------------
id   |   name
--------------
1    | value 1
2    | value 2
3    | value 3
--------------
```

I want the created array to be as simple as possible like value1,value2,value3

I am using  this function

```
function getAll()
    {
        //select all data
        $sql = "SELECT name FROM " . $this->table_name . "  ORDER BY id";

        $prep_state = $this->db_conn->prepare($sql);
        $prep_state->execute();

        $row = $prep_state->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $this->name = $row['name'];
    }
```

Is there a simple way to do it, perhaps with another PDO Mode like for example is done with PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE, or a should take a different approach?

**UPDATE** - This way it worked (*thanks to @u_mulder*)

```
function getAll()
{
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM " . $this->table_name . "  ORDER BY id";
    $prep_state = $this->db_conn->prepare($sql);
    $prep_state->execute();

    $names = $prep_state->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0); 
    return(implode(",",$names));

}
```

Comment: What does `Create single array` mean here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use PDO to fetch results array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911757/how-to-use-pdo-to-fetch-results-array-in-php)

Comment: single dimension... like array(value1,value2,value3);

Comment: Why not use `fetchAll` instead of `fetch` since you want to return all rows?

Comment: Yes, fetchAll did it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` mode:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM " . $this->table_name . "  ORDER BY id";
$prep_state = $this->db_conn->prepare($sql);
$prep_state->execute();

// 0 indicates first column of result
$names = $prep_state->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0); 
print_r($names);
// then do what you want.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. instead of print_r i just added return(implode(",",$names));

Answer (score 1):

if youe want all the name in an array   you could  try group_concat and explode

```
function getAll()
{
    //select all data
    $sql = "SELECT group_cancat(name) name FROM " . $this->table_name . "  ORDER BY id";

    $prep_state = $this->db_conn->prepare($sql);
    $prep_state->execute();

    $row = $prep_state->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // build an array from the concatenated  string pf names 
    $myArray = explode(',',  $row['name']);

    return $myArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the fetchAll method which returns an array, and then just return your array in a variable that you can use.

```
function getAll()
    {
        //select all data
        $sql = "SELECT name FROM " . $this->table_name . "  ORDER BY id";

        $prep_state = $this->db_conn->prepare($sql);
        $prep_state->execute();

        $row = $prep_state->fetchAll(); //changed this
        $return $row; //and this
    }
```

Then to get the values out of this array.

```
foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
//echo your results
}
```

The key will be the id and the value will be the name.