# How to return MySQL records via PHP function call using PDO and Prepared Statements?

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I am trying to find the best way to get records from a MySQL table via a PHP function call using a prepared statement and PDO?

Efficiency is not the issue (I am sure there is perhaps a faster way or more memory efficient way to accomplish this task). My goal is to make the code simple, with one call to a function for to obtain records via a PHP function call and a using PDO prepared statement.

The caller so far looks like this:

```
$records = DB_Get_Records($pdo_connection, '"SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID = ?', array($record_id);`
```

And the function looks like this:

```
function DB_Get_Records(&$pdo_connection, &$sql_statement, &$records_located, &$select_string, &$param_array) {
    $sql_statement = $pdo_connection->prepare($select_string);
    $sql_statement->execute($param_array);
    $records_located = $sql_statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $records_located;
```

Because of the scope of the params, I am using pass by reference. But I am not sure how to best define in the main portion of the script. If I use pass by value, I believe that all results will be lost after returning from the function.

The confusion is how to define them prior to the function call so that they will receive the data. I am not sure if I have to reserve space of a some sort prior to calling the function. When using

```
$records_located = $sql_statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

In either the main portion of the script or the function, $records_located receives the records.
But trying to path this information from the caller to the main is not clear to me. When used in the function, the fetch statement (I believe) will create the necessary space using $records_located as the pointer. The question that pops up seems to be is how? Is the receiving variable used to create an array and then setting a point to $records_located variable? If so, then the scope would of the array would likely be limited to the function call. And if that is the case, then -- although the data pointer is retained -- the actual data returned from fetch would be gone after the function returns.

Hopefully, I am missing something here or overthinking the issue.

Again, it is not about trying to maximize speed of memory usage. It is simply about making simple calls to the database of one line instead of many lines to setup each call to get records.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911757/how-to-use-pdo-to-fetch-results-array-in-php is what you are after?

Comment: Thank you, Nigel, for the info. That, unfortunately, doesn't seem to apply. I understand the fetch basics and have that part working. It is more a matter of scope at this point.

Comment: Looks like you need to forget all about allocating memory and who does what where, PHP mostly does that for you.  If you change all of your parameters to NOT be passed by reference and then `return $sql_statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`  This will just return an array of the results and no scope is involved.

Comment: You are 100% correct, Nigel. TX! Works perfectly. I was overthinking the situation. Will accept your information as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to forget all about allocating memory and who does what where, PHP mostly does that for you. If you change all of your parameters to **NOT** be passed by reference and then

```
return $sql_statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This will just return an array of the results and no scope is involved